# Doubly linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, beginner, linked-list

I'm quite new to C, and I'm looking for feedback on this (doubly) linked list code.

Once I get to the add and remove methods, I feel like the code goes downhill. I'm looking for any potential errors I haven't spotted, and improvements that could be made for efficiency/tidiness.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
};

struct listset {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    int current_elements;
};

struct listset * new_listset(){
    struct listset *new_list = malloc(sizeof(struct listset));
    new_list ->head = NULL;
    new_list ->tail = NULL;

    return new_list;
};

struct node *listset_lookup(struct listset *this, int item){
    struct node *curr_elem = this->head;
    if(!curr_elem) return NULL;
    while(item != curr_elem->data){
        if(curr_elem->next==NULL)return NULL;
        curr_elem = curr_elem->next;
    }
    return curr_elem;
}

void listset_add(struct listset *this, int item){
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node -> data = item;
    new_node ->next = NULL;
    if(!this->head) {
        new_node->previous = NULL;
        this->head = this->tail = new_node;
    }
    else{
        this->tail->next = new_node;
    }
    this->current_elements++;
}
void listset_remove(struct listset *this, int item){
    struct node *elem_remove = listset_lookup(this, item);
    if(!elem_remove) return;
    if(elem_remove->next && elem_remove->previous) elem_remove->previous->next = elem_remove->next;
    else if (elem_remove->previous && !elem_remove->previous){
        elem_remove->previous->next=NULL;
        this->tail = elem_remove->previous;
    }
    else{
        this->tail = NULL;
        this->head = NULL;
    }
    free(elem_remove);
}
```

Comment: In the listset_add you do not change the tail in the `else` block: `this->tail = new_node`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually "off-topic" because it doesn't work.  You should really
include a short `main` that illustrates its use and allows it to be tested.  All the same, here are some comments.

Be consistent with spacing.  My preference is for no spaces around `->` and
for a space after keywords (`if`, `while` etc).

Variable naming.  Your names are not to my taste, often too long:

- Rename `previous` as `prev`, `current_elements` as `n_elements`
- Rename `this` globally as `list` - `this` means nothing whereas `list` is
  clearly a list.
- Rename `item` as `data`.  It is called `data` within the `node` structure so
  why not be consistent?
- `new_listset` would perhaps be more consistent with the other functions if
  named `listset_new`.  It also needs a `void` parameter list.

Function `listset_lookup` tests the wrong condition in the loop.  Better to
test for the end of the list:

```
struct node *listset_lookup(const struct listset *list, int data)
{
    struct node *n = list->head;
    while (n) {
        if (data == n->data) {
            break;
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Notice also that the parameter `list` is `const` (as you don't alter it).  Also
note that writing this with a short variable name makes it much more readable
compared to the dense text that results from a longer name.  In a ten line
function with only 3 variables there is really nothing wrong (and a lot right)
with using such a short name.

Your `listset_add` is missing two terms in the `else` clause and should test
for `malloc` failure (and return something to show whether it failed).  I
would also rename `new_node` as simple `n` - again, it is a short function (as
most should be) and so this is ok.

```
static struct node* listset_add(struct listset *list, int data)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (n) {
        n->data = data;
        n->next = NULL;
        if (!list->head) {
            n->prev = NULL;
            list->head = list->tail = n;
        } else {
            n->prev = list->tail; // new
            list->tail->next = n;
            list->tail = n;       // new
        }
        list->n_elements++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Your `listset_remove` is hard to read and wrong.  Again, a shorter variable
name would help.  You should also avoid long lines such as:

```
if(elem_remove->next && elem_remove->previous) elem_remove->previous->next = elem_remove->next;
```

This is much clearer as:

```
if (n->next && n->previous) {
    n->previous->next = n->next;
}
```

All the same, it is perhaps wrong.  And this:

```
else if (elem_remove->previous && !elem_remove->previous){
```

is quite clearly not sensible.  You also don't decrement the element count.
The correct function is:

```
static void listset_remove(struct listset *list, int data)
{
    struct node *n = listset_lookup(list, data);
    if (!n) return;

    if (n->prev) {
        n->prev->next = n->next;
    } else {
        list->head = n->next;
    }
    if (n->next) {
        n->next->prev = n->prev;
    } else {
        list->tail = n->prev;
    }
    list->n_elements--;
    free(n);
}
```

Here's what I used to test it:

```
static void listset_print(const struct listset *list)
{
    struct node *n = list->head;
    while (n) {
        printf("%d ", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf(" : ");

    n = list->tail;
    while (n) {
        printf("%d ", n->data);
        n = n->previous;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct listset *list = new_listset();
    listset_add(list, 1);
    listset_add(list, 2);
    listset_add(list, 3);
    listset_add(list, 4);
    listset_add(list, 5);
    listset_print(list);
    listset_remove(list, 6);
    listset_print(list);
    listset_remove(list, 1);
    listset_print(list);
    listset_remove(list, 5);
    listset_print(list);
    listset_remove(list, 3);
    listset_print(list);
    listset_remove(list, 2);
    listset_print(list);
    listset_remove(list, 4);
    listset_print(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of the list looks correct but the coding style is not neat yet. There are some suggestions:

- There are different recommendations on how to format the type of the pointers, but probably all agree that the character `*` is the part of the type. So it is better to always keep it near the type.
- The code is unreasonably compacted. It is good if you want to have a whole algorithm on one screen but most likely you will spend most of the time focusing on its particular aspects so the readability of the individual fragments prevails.
- develop a good habit of putting constants at the first place in logical expressions.
- it is cool that you know this trick `a = b = NULL` but you do not use it consistently in the code - anyway, it is better to not use it.
- prefer positive constructions in `if`s because it is very easy to overlook just the single `!` in the boolean expression.
- `current_elements` is not a quite right name for the variable that contains the size of the list. `size` is much better :)
- avoid unnecessary shorten variable names: is there a strong reason to use `curr_elem` instead of just `current` or `element`?

### Logic

- consider `calloc` - it clears the memory so you do not need to null all the structure variables - they will be set to zeroes.
- `listset_add` should be revised - it does not set `this->tail` and `new_node->previous` if `NULL != this->head`
- `listset_remove` should be revised - it does not set `elem_remove->next->previous` correctly, `elem_remove->previous && !elem_remove->previous` is never true.
- `list_free` that releases all the elements and list itself in one operation will be very handy.

Comment: I don't agree that '*' is part of the type. If I define `int *a, b;` and `int* a, b;`, the second (which would be logical if the * is part of the type) gives the impression that `b` is a pointer to int, which it clearly isn't.  Defining two variables in this way would be unwise, but is legal.

Comment: Thank you for writing this up. By putting constants first do you mean for example: if(NULL == x) rather than if(x == NULL)?

Comment: The `if (NULL == x)` is better because the compiler will warn you if you forget one `=` and write `if (NULL = x)`. The `if (x = NULL)` is valid construction that can be easy overlooked.

Comment: @WilliamMorris I understand you point but it is about C syntax which is clumsy sometimes, not about the concept. The code review is all about helping other to avoid what is legal and syntactically correct but unwise, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexAtNet Compilers can and do check for that already. Yoda conditions haven't been useful for a long time (or arguably ever).

Comment: @Corbin, so could you please go one step forward and provide user31885 with instructions on how to configure his or her compiler correctly because this check is not enabled by default in most of the compilers?

Comment: Depends on the compiler. The short answer though is to just crank up warnings as high as they'll go and it will surely be included.

Answer (score 0):

I will try not to repeat what was said in the comments and in Alex' answer.

In `new_listset()` you forgot to initialize `current_elements` to zero. If you replace `malloc` with `calloc`, you will not need to do that. In that case, you can also remove initializations of `head` and `tail`, since `NULL == (void*)0`.

I find your lookup a bit counter-intuitive. I'd do it like this:

```
struct node *listset_lookup(struct listset *this, int item){
    struct node *curr_elem = this->head;
    while (curr_elem) {
        if (curr_elem->data == item) return curr_elem;
        curr_elem = curr_elem->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

or, even more intuitive (for me, at least):

```
struct node *listset_lookup(struct listset *this, int item){
    struct node *curr_elem;
    for (curr_elem = this->head; curr_elem; curr_elem = curr_elem->next)
        if (curr_elem->data == item) return curr_elem;
    return NULL;
}
```

There are several reasons I like it this way better.

1. This is a standard "go through the whole list and do something" loop, instead of your "do something special (loop until the element is found)".
2. My code doesn't have check for `NULL` on two places.
3. Each step is dealing with the "current" element. In your code, you have `if` checking the *next* element, which is an approach I prefer to avoid if it is reasonably possible.

Mind you, this is not a big deal, and it is alright if you want to keep your version.

Maybe a bit more important remark is regarding the `listset_remove()` function. I'd make it return `int`, which would be the count of the elements removed. This way, wherever you've called it, you would know if it has removed anything. You could also add a third parameter which would say how many items can be removed at most (zero for all of them), so that more than one item can be removed if some are equal among themselves.

By the way, you forgot to decrease `this->current_elements` in that function.

Lastly, I suggest adding checks if your `malloc`/`calloc` calls were successful.